# is it possible to free allocated memory output from C++

Tags: android, c++, memory, asynchronous, android-ndk

I would like to know if it is possible to free a return value from C++. I am using NDK in C++ to build an android native library.

I would like to do something like this :

In my C++ code :

The JNI entry point

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_myMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
    int len = 16;
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(len);
    jbyteArray array = env->NewByteArray (len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion (array, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));
    std::thread{&MyClass::asynchronousFree, this, array}.detach();
    return array;
}
```

And a method called asynchronously to free the return value

```
void Myclass::asynchronousFree(jbytearray array){
    //code to free the memory after a specified time
}
```

In my Android code :

```
void process(){
    byte[] array = ndk.myMethod();
    //do some stuff with the array
    //here i need array erased from memory
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you talking about freeing `buf`? If so, you can do that right after `SetByteArrayRegion`, since `SetByteArrayRegion` will copy the data.

Comment: Thanks for this reponse. I am not talking about freeing buf. I am talking freeing the java array variable wich is a JNI proxy of C++ jbytearray array variable. I would like to free the Java array variable.

Comment: Well, `NewByteArray` creates a local reference to a Java `byte[]`. That local reference will IIRC be deleted automatically when your current thread detaches from the VM or the native code returns back to Java code. At that point, if no one else holds a reference to the Java object, that object would be a candidate for garbage collection. Like Alex Cohn said, you could overwrite the array with garbage before it gets collected, but then you need a way of knowing when `process` is done using the array.

Comment: I can assume that i wan't to delete the array after a few period like 100 milliseconds. In my context i assume that if the process is not completed within this period of time it is a kind of attack. I really need that this sensitive variable live a few time in memory

Answer (score 0):

Doing this from C++ is not different from doing same from Java. Which means, given a reference to an array, or any other Java object, you cannot force this object into non-existence, but you can change its properties.

For an array, it's length is immutable, but the elements are not. Your `asynchronousFree()` method can set all the elements to 0, or otherwise indicate that the array is not valid anymore.

To have better control over the situation, you can use any Java container you like, including ArrayList which is the closest to array re it's functionality, or ByteBuffer.

All such objects support this or that clear(), reset(), or resize(0) method which will essentially release the elements. As always in Java, some other code may still keep a reference to any of the elements. Even worse, for any data structure you propose, there is always a way to perform "deep copy" and keep the values that you want to destroy.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean. However it is a matter of security. I don't wan't to trust Java code because it is easier to reverse engineer it and to tamper it. I wan't to erase the java byte array returned by the NDK

Comment: As a matter of security, I don't see the difference between setting all the elements of the array to garbage, and discarding the array. I don't understand what kind of anti-tampering you can achieve this way, because  even if you destroy everything in your **asynchronousFree()**, the Java consumer can copy the contents to a persistent array which is not controlled by your library.

Comment: Yes i see. Even if i found a way to delete the java byte array i can't control the copy of the returned NDK value.

Comment: it's important to understand that there is nothing JNI-specific in this scenario. All what can be don, can be done in pure Java. Whatever cannot be done in pure Java, will not become possible because it comes from a native library.